# Synchronization scenario for an on-prem VM and a GCP snaphot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, data-migration, google-migrate-for-compute-engine

I need to migrate a VM from on-prem to GCP using Velostrata , which I can do in a straight forward way.

Post migration , I want to save this image as a DR for a warm back up scenario.

There are two types VMs , first a VM that hosts a stateless application and second type of VMs are the ones that have applications that  hold stateful data.

My questions is how do we keep these VMs images on GCP up to date with all the updates that happen on-prem , for both those type of VMs.

Do I use Velostrata  to migrate the VM again i.e every time an update is made on-prem, are there any other approaches or tools?

Comment: Add to your question what devops procedures you are using. If none, you have a terrible future in front of you - start tooling up now. If you are, then I would use warm standby systems and deploy changes to the cloud at the same time (staged) as on-prem.

Comment: How would I deploy a change to the cloud at the same time ?meaning migrate the VM again drom on-prem to GCP using Velostrata or use any other DevOps tool?

Comment: The first step is to learn how to perform DevOps and then get procedures, methods and tooling in place. There are a zillion tools out there. The process of develop, test, deploy can be simple or very complicated. It is like asking how do I cook dinner and serve it - what is your kitchen, what are you cooking, how many people are eating? The details will change the solution. Feeding four people is very different from 4,000. The same with DevOps. Velostrata is just one component in what should be an entire process.

Comment: My loose thinking is that the notion behind Velostrata is that of migration ... and not any for of replication.  When you migrate an on-premises VM to GCP using Velostrata, I had assumed that the on-premises VMWare VM would be shutdown and the GCP Compute Engine spin up.  Then the data is moved from on-premises to GCP over time.  After all the data has moved up, then you can detach the VM on premises and presumably delete it.  At this point your VM will now be in the cloud and that is where you would exclusively work with it.  What would you later do on-premises?